# Using a VPN inside a virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn, virtualization, openvpn

If I use VPN software (on a gust windows VM) to connect to a certain server (not via port 80), can the server see the host IP? I have an expressVPN subscription, planning to use it with virtualbox. What kind of network setting do I need (like Nat or bridged, etc)

Answer (score 1):

The expressVPN application should connect to the expressVPN servers and then make the connection to the destination server from there. Therefore, the destination server should only see expressVPN's IP address.

If the guest OS is not up to date with security updates, there may be privacy concerns from that, but that's beyond the scope of the question.